# How to combine eslint 'git-ignore style patterns'

Tags: eslint

I want to use https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-restricted-imports to match specific imports.

It should match `**/selectors` and should not match `**.selectors`.

The docs say it uses 'git-ignore style patterns' but I am unable to combine them.

```json
"no-restricted-imports": [
          "error",
          {
            "patterns": [
              {
                "group": ["**/selectors !/**.selectors"],
                "message": "Do not do that"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
```